# Prove that $f(x)=x^2 \cdot \lfloor {\frac{1}{x^2}}\rfloor$ is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

> I want to prove that $f(x)=x^2 \cdot \lfloor {\frac{1}{x^2}}\rfloor$ is continuous on its domain.

This is what I have come up with so far : I know that the floor function is continuous over $\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Z}$,and I think this implies that $f$ is continuous over $\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Z}$. I think that $f(x) =0$,$\forall x \in \mathbb{Z} $ and as a result $f$ is continuous on its domain. Is this right?

Comment: I am currently trying to fix my latex, I am writing from my mobile.

Comment: i suggested an edit, is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. I have always had issues with the floor function in latex.

Comment: You are correct, it is continuous on its domain.

Comment: @Matthew Liu it looks like it isn't, I also believed it was.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your function is not continuous, unfortunately.

For instance, $f(1)= 1$, but for all $x > 1$, you have $f(x) = 0$.

Comment: And this implies that it is discontinuous because $\lim \limits_{x \to 1^{+}} f(x) =0$?

Comment: Yes ! $\lim_{x \rightarrow 1^+} f(x) = 0 \neq f(1)$.

Answer (score 3):

Is it continuosus? This is the graph: [image]

It is not continuous at $x=1$ which is in domain.

$$\lim_{x\to 1_{-} } f(x) =1 \ne 0 =\lim_{x\to 1_{+} } f(x)$$

Comment: Thank you for the graph! Could you tell me what software you used to make it?

Comment: Geogebra .......